# how to load Ckeditor with IMCE file browser through javascript

Tags: 7, javascript, wysiwyg, files

I have installed CKeditor and IMCE modules for Drupal7.
Now when i click on a button in my page, i want to load the ckeditor with IMCE support (File browser option).

How to achieve this with javascript?
So far, i am loading the ckeditor this way, but it is not showing a file browser button for image:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('text_'+id, { 
    width: 630,
    height: 300
});

CKEDITOR.config.toolbar = [
    ['Bold','Italic','Underline']
];

CKEDITOR.config.extraPlugins = 'imce';
```

The strange thing is that, the Image dialog has "Browse Server" button for the textarea under the form that is created with Drupal Form API, but when i try to apply ckeditor for a custom textarea through javascript, i don't see the "Browse Server" button for Image dialog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i figured it myself, after referring to some of the Drupal forum posts, like [**this one**](https://drupal.org/node/1040446#comment-4050528). I removed the 'Image' button in ckeditor toolbar, and instead used the 'IMCE' button. I realized that i must

1. Assign a profile to the users under: admin/config/media/imce
2. Under admin/config/content/ckeditor/edit/Full > Editor Appearance, add 'IMCE' button in the 'Used Buttons' area and check the option "Plugin for inserting files from imce without image dialog" under Plugins. (assuming that i am using 'Full' ckeditor profile)
3. Under admin/config/content/ckeditor/edit/Full > File browser settings > select 'IMCE' for all File browser type options.
4. Include the 'IMCE' option while applying the ckeditor for the textarea, like:

   CKEDITOR.config.toolbar = [['Bold','Italic','Underline',
   '-','JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','-','IMCE','Undo','Redo']];

Finally this is what i achieved in the editor:

[image]